# How do you write a full stack trace to the log?

Tags: java, stack-trace

I was catching an exception and trying to write the stack trace to the logs like this:

```
log.warn(e.getMessage());
```

But all it said was

```
null
```

So I changed it to

```
log.warn(e.toString());
```

And now it says only

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How do I write the full stack trace to the log so I can see where this Exception is being generated in the app?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Usually:

```
log.warn("message", e);
```

But it depends on your logging framework too.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
logger.log(Level.WARN, "logged exception", ex);
```

or

```
logger.warn("logged exception", ex);
```

---

**Resources :**

- [How to print the stack trace of an exception using Log4J (or Commons Logging)](http://devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-print-exception-stack-trace-using-log4j-commons)
- [logging.apache.org - `Category`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html)

Answer (score 7):

If you using Java 8 you can do the following:

```
LOGGER.error("Caught exception while methodX. Please investigate: " 
    + exception 
    + Arrays.asList(exception.getStackTrace())
    .stream()
    .map(Objects::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
);
```

Comment: It works just fine and it's also useful during debugging sessions when exceptions are not properly logged.

Comment: I experienced processing above was much slower than log.error("message", e);  I have tried on my debug session, worth checking it out especially if you write a global handler.

Comment: Arrays.asList(...).stream() can be simplified to Arrays.stream(e.getStackTrace())

Answer (score 5):

Using log4j this is done with:

```
logger.error("An error occurred", exception);
```

The first argument is a message to be displayed, the second is the exception (throwable) whose stacktrace is logged.

Another option is commons-logging, where it's the same:

```
log.error("Message", exception);
```

With java.util.logging this can be done via:

```
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Message", exception);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your exception method, the underlying `String` which contains the message is `null`.

The above answer, now struck out, still holds, except that `e` is not null, but the `detailMessage` private instance variable on the `Throwable` class is null, which is why `e.getMessage()` is the String `null`, but `e.toString()` (which calls underlying *null* `detailMessage.toString`) throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: if e was null, log.warn(e.getMessage()); would throw exception and it would not print "null".

Comment: No it wouldn't, it would throw a NPE

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Java version previous to 8, you can try this:

```
            LOGGER.error("Error al recuperar proveedores de la base de datos: " + 
            e + Arrays.asList(e.getStackTrace()).stream().map(new Function(){
                    @Override
                    public Object apply(Object t) {
                        return t.toString();
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```