# ZipOutPutStream throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am trying to Zip file using `ZipOutputStream` but it's throwing `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` while passing a `FileOutPutStream` object. 
The code was working fine when I ran it as a separate java class but when I integrated it with my project, it's throwing the exception.

I used this code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

try{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Report.zip");

    //error throwing at this point (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)

    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Report.xls");

    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Report.xls"));

    int len;

    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }

    in.close();

    zos.closeEntry();

    zos.close();
}catch(IOException ex){
           Log.report.debug(ex.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Please post the _full_ stacktrace

Comment: Where is your `buffer`?

Comment: Hi Ryan
that is the only thing showing in stacktrace

Comment: buffer array is not declared.

Comment: @user2677254 No, it isn't. Your stack trace should look like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Hi inquisitor
I have edited the code with buffer.

Comment: I think it is obvious that his buffer and declared and initialised somewhere before that code gets executed... If it wasn't, he wouldn't be able to run his code at all.. Also, how would the lack of a byte array declaration cause his type of error!?

Comment: Hi Ryan
I cant print stack trace to our Log so I used toString to print the error

Comment: Not entirely sure why you're getting this error, but I would start by declaring your buffer.  Simply add this before your loop `byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];`

Comment: @inquisitor His code wouldn't execute if he didn't have that buffer. That is not his problem.

Comment: @JoshM, thanks I'm still a noob to programming and was just trying to help based on what was provided

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717249/how-do-you-write-a-full-stack-trace-to-the-log for how to get the full stacktrace

Comment: Hi b.buchhold
I will use the example to get full stack trace
thanku :)

Comment: @user2677254 you should be downvoted because you must run your code seperately before posting here.

Comment: Try: `new ZipOutputStream(fos)` instead.

Comment: @JoshM the code is working fine, but didn't worked after integrating into project. so definitely issue raises on integrating code with project.